# userform combobox item loading procedure error/ sub or function not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a Userform where once the userform is initialized, there is a combobox which list a range of information from a specific worksheet that people can select.
Adding just basic information to a combobox I can do, using combobox.additem "1" for example, but to get it to read a range I am getting a sub or function not defined error.

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim rulesSheet As Worksheet                 
    Set rulesSheet = Sheets("Rules")

    I = 1

    Do
        comboboxadd
        iteminbox = rulesSheet.Range("A" & I)
        CostCentreCMBox.AddItem (iteminbox)
        I = I + 1
    Loop Until iteminbox = " "

    CostCentreCMBox.ListIndex = 0  
End Sub
```

I would like my combobox to add items in the range of worksheet "rules" column A, row (as many as that have information in), once userform as me initialized

Comment: What line do you get the error in? What is the use of `comboboxadd`?

Comment: When debugging it’s the first line public sub user_form initialise() that highlight yellow.

Comment: Try using `F8` to step through the subroutine and see where it breaks. One thing that's problematic is `Set rulesSheet = Sheets("Rules")`, you're missing a workbook reference.

Comment: I’ve done f8 and actually it’s the comboboxadd line that’s highlighting the error.          Wouldn’t the workbook reference just be the workbook I’m on? Will it need referencing?

Comment: What is comboboxadd ? Is it a sub that you made? Also its good practice (and avoids a lot of errors) to reference the workbook. It sometimes acts very strange if you don't.

Comment: If comboboxadd isn't a function or other sub you made, it's nonsense code. What do you want to achieve with that line? Seems like there already is a combobox in the UF, try just deleting that line.

Comment: Hello tim Thankyou for your help and advice with best practice. I’ll make note of that going forward.. you are right that was nonsense code.. thankfully I’ve now fixed it just did it a different way but got results I needed. Thankyou